# Best Practices to Store Only Year In SQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am Saving Student Passing Year Into Database.

I am Little confuse about how do I save **YEAR**  Into SQL. 
I am using Codeigniter Framework.

Here is my HTML Input code:

```
 <input type="text" name="passing_year" id="passing_year" required />
```

I lookup some suggestion but not get it properly.
So the Problem is:

What should I use in SQL datatype. 
**Integer or Data**

Why?

I have tried to convert the year into date but I get Current Data in that process. Here is the code.

```
$sqlDataFormate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year));
```

In this code the problem is that, if send any year (2010, 2011, etc) I get **2017-06-05**

Is it possible that if i select "2010" from year then I can save it like "2010-01-01" ? by using strtotime.

Here is the picture of my html input datepiker.
[image]

Comment: See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/year.html, and try: `$sqlDataFormate = date('Y', strtotime($year));`

Comment: store it as smallint

Comment: @JustBaron Still i got 2017 for any year. I mean if  I choose 2011 then it still convert it to 2017 after

Comment: What is the value of `$year`?

Comment: $year is like 2010, 2011, etc  @JustBaron

Comment: So why the need to convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can get year by passing only year parameter to function like this**

```
$sqlDataFormate = date('Y', strtotime($year));
```

Comment: if i select 2010 then can i save 2010-01-01 in sql ? @Nirajpatel

Comment: from this string you get 2010

Comment: means you want every time 2017 in all condition..?

Comment: no sir, if i choose 2010 then i want 2010 but is it possible that if i choose 2010 then i can save it as 2010-01-01

Comment: yes ofcourse you can covert it to datestring by year and save it to your database

Comment: sir, so is your answer is capable of doing that?

Comment: did you ever try  mktime() function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145865/discussion-between-niraj-patel-and-always-a-learner).